# How to add rounded corners to a single side in HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css, button, shapes, border-radius

And yes, the only thing I want to do is apply the border-radius attribute(or something like that) do just 1 corner to a button just like this: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm9VN.jpg"

> Don't worry, the link is generated by StackOverFlow so nothing to worry about the link.

Also, I need to include some code otherwise my question will be closed:
Here's what I have tried:

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 30;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
```

But it applies the property to all the corners which is not what I want.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following snippet, for more info take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius):

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid #00bfff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30%;
  border-top-right-radius: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #00bfff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
```